# ValueError: Shapes (1024, 3) and (1024, 1024, 3) are incompatible

Tags: tensorflow

I have a array as size - 1024, 1024, 3 and need to  create a FIFOQueue of this size.

```
a  = np.zeros((1024, 1024, 3))
dtypes=[tf.float32]
print len(dtypes)
shapes=[1024, 1024, 3]
print len(shapes)
q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=200,dtypes=dtypes,shapes=shapes)
```

When I tried this I get this error -

```
ValueError: Shapes (1024, 3) and (1024, 1024, 3) are incompatible
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted runs without error. I suspect there is a missing line:

```
enqueue_op = q.enqueue_many(a)
```

...which when executed gives the exception:

```
ValueError: Shapes (1024, 3) and (1024, 1024, 3) are incompatible
```

There are two possible solutions:

1. If you want to enqueue the array as a single element, you should use `q.enqueue(a)` instead of `q.enqueue_many(a)`
2. If you want to enqueue the array as 1024 separate elements, you should define `shapes = [1024, 3]`, which is the shape of a single element when using `q.enqueue_many(a)`.

Comment: Thanks..Thats correct..Im trying to create a FIFOQueue to queue my input data but input data is a numpy array. Is there a recommended way to directly pass this numpy array directly to the FIFOQueue.

Comment: Either of option 1 or 2 should work, depending on whether you want to get one element out of the queue (option 1), or many elements or different-sized batches (option 2).

Comment: Im unable to feed the feed_dict using queue..Here is a related posts - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47315454/tensorflow-error-you-must-feed-a-value-for-placeholder-tensor-in